# Subquery automatically producing cross join

Tags: sql, subquery, cross-join

I am not certain WHY but when I follow the example (from the northwind datase in a ms sql server) to do a subquery on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 by typing in the code like shown below,

```
Select Orders.OrderID, 
       (Select Customers.CompanyName 
          From Customers 
          Where Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID) As Company Name
  From Orders, 
       Customers
```

This sql code with subquery automatically gained a cross join and become

```
    Select Orders.OrderID,
           (Select Customers.CompanyName 
              From Customers
             Where Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID) As Company Name
      From Orders 
CROSS JOIN Customers as Customers_1
```

I have played around with several variation of this but with no luck in eliminating this problem.  Is this a known bug for microsoft sql server management studio 2008? If so, has it been patched, how do I find the patched? Otherwise, how can I report this to Microsoft and get them to really fixed it quickly?

In my actual query, I need to query/lookup the name of this particular table about 50 times by equating the ID and I think it is simply dumb having to do a JOIN of any sort for this because the code is crumpy, VERY long, and performance may be poor?

Comment: The queries are equivalent - the first is using ANSI-89 syntax, the latter uses ANSI-92 syntax.  The subselect doesn't change that there is a cartesian product of ORDERS and CUSTOMERS...

Answer (score 2):

The subquery isn't causing the cross join, the lack of a condition controlling the join is.  You need something like this:

```
Select Orders.OrderID, (Select Customers.CompanyName From Customers Where Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID) As Company Name 
From Orders, Customers
Where Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
```

Comment: thank you sir for your most kind reply but isn't the objective of doing a subquery is that I can do the condition controlling within the subquery ONLY need not repeat it again in the main Select's WHERE clause???

Comment: but isn't the objective of doing a subquery is so I can do the condition controlling within the subquery ONLY and need not repeat it again in the main Select's WHERE clause??? elsewise, I need to "lookup/query" this particular table 50 times and the Where clause would be like Where (Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID) and (Orders.CustomerID1 = Customers.CustomerID) and (Orders.CustomerID2 = Customers.CustomerID) and ...   Finally, I do not know what result I be getting back??? Please do kindly help!

Comment: @Peter -- no.  That is not how SQL works.  Try the example in my answer.  The only reason to do a sub-query is to a group by or aggregate.

Comment: @Hogan is right.  You don't even need the subquery in your case.  I didn't even look at what you were actually trying to do with the subquery, but just saw that you needed to fix your where clause.  Personally, I actually prefer joins using the syntax `inner join customers on <condition>`.

Comment: @squawknull - an inner join will give him different results than he wants I expect.

Comment: I am doing subquery because I have a table A that have encrypted data and to decypher it, I need to reference to a specific table, X. A contains 50 encrypted columns so I need to look up X 50 times. This is a simple and direct lookup/substitution of A.ID/Code to X.Name/meaning with A.ID = X.ID ONLY. I am now using left outer join for the job but it hung the system perhaps because there is just too many stacks of nested joins. I therefore try to do it via subquery thinking it would work. If I revert by to left outer join, how should I better write it then? I thank you for your kind assistance.

Comment: Don't use left outer join -- use left join.  Just like in my answer.  If you use left join 50 times it will be fine.  If you use left outer join 50 time you will be in a world of hurt that will product a new table where the number of rows in the result will be x*50 raised to the power of x (where x is number of rows in your target table).  Just use left join.

Comment: Understood but is there a method to do this without using any JOIN. It is afterall a very simple lookup and if possible, I really do not want to do left join 50 times... Honestly, the code is impossible to read and COUNT... Please do HELP.

Comment: The left join will likely be more efficient than a subquery.  However, from the sound of it, you may have your left join going the wrong direction.  A left join is not a full join.  You have to know whether rows will ALWAYS match between both tables.  If sometimes there will be no match, and in that case you just want a NULL to be produced, then a left inner join is not what you want.  Can you by chance paste your query with joins into your question above, as there may be something simple to fix there.  My guess is that your join is just going the wrong direction, causing a cartesian product.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why a sub-query is suggested by your book -- I would do it like this:

```
Select Orders.OrderID, Customers.CompanyName 
  From Orders 
  left join Customers on Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should be a correlated-subquery

Select Orders.OrderID,

```
   (Select Customers.CompanyName 
      From Customers 
      Where **Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID**) As Company Name
```

From Orders

--, 
--       Customers

Why would you need Customers again when the inner Correlated Subquery brings the customer Name for each Order that is processed?

The Management Studio's insistence on adding CROSS JOIN is a warning that you are doing something strange.  Trying to query two tables: Customer,Orders without any join condition.

Also, the query optimizer will usually convert these correlated sub-queries into joins during processing, but you can use the clearer syntax where appropriate.

Where is it appropriate? Particularly if you need to generate some sort of aggregate on the inner query.